# Can I digitally sign iOS source code so that it's traceable?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I would like to sell some source code for an iOS game. Is there any way to digitally sign it so I can trace it, were the customer to then re-sell the source code without permission?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Source code is text, so if by digitally sign you mean encrypt, then they wouldn't be able to compile it. You could always give them just a static library compiled from your source, so they wouldn't actually have the source code itself, and you could embed in the code something that gathers info about the app its included in and sends that back to you. But if you give them source code, there's no way to technically prevent them from sharing it or to be guaranteed to find out about it.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I thought as much. Would I be able to hide something in the source code, hope they don't find it ... and if they don't then trace that back to them by downloading from the app store and then examining the download?

Comment: iOS apps on the store are encrypted, so you wouldn't be able to just "examine" it to find your code. If you suspected an app contained your source code illegally, you would probably have to contact the app developer to inquire, or possibly pursue legal action if they refused to cooperate. But it seems like more hassle than it's worth. You could always hide something in the code to communicate usage information back to you, and hope they don't spot it and remove it. Then you would know if it's used in an app that's not theirs. But they could easily defeat that by examining the code.